# Fusion tables OR is not supported

Tags: google-fusion-tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fusion Tables filter conditions OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438720/fusion-tables-filter-conditions-or)

In fusion tables, I try make this query

```
  select col0 from xyz col1 = value1 or col2 = value2
```

but in fusion tables [OR is not supported](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference).

How I can make this query ? 
If I make two query, I get duplicate info.

Comment: your query makes no sense. do you want to select from a table where col1 - value1 or col2 - value2?

Comment: yes, why the query don't have sense ?

Comment: because you're selecting a different column than the values that you want

Comment: select from xyz (col1, col2) where value matches (value1, value2);